# .htaccess regex rewrite rule

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following regex:

```
RewriteRule ^blogs/([^/]*)/([^/]*) blogs/index.php?blogger=$1&blog=$2
```

This works fine for the following cases:

- http://myurl.com/blogs/blog-name/blog-article/
- http://myurl.com/blogs/blog-name/blog-article
- http://myurl.com/blogs/blog-name/

however it does not handle:

- http://myurl.com/blogs/blog-name

How can I make the "/" separator optional in this regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use:

```
^blogs/([^/]*)(/([^/]*))?
```

And you'd just have to check and make sure that `$2` is still correct (with the two capture groups, it might be `$3`… I can't remember).

Comment: Having the ? seems to remove the vars passed on to the script inn .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

If the '?' is causing troubles then try:

```
^blogs/([^/]*)(/([^/]*)){0,1}
```