# 301 redirect in .htaccess for 30,000 errors

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I've been tasked to clean up 30,000 or so url errors left behind from an old website as the result of a redesign and development.

I normally use .htaccess to do this, but I doubt it would be wise to have 30,000 301 redirects inside the .htaccess file!

What methods have some of you used to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would like to know the answer too! especially when you are using smarty template

Comment: You can use regex expression for this... simply like this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077705/htaccess-regex-rewrite-rule

Comment: I find some kind of patterns and different scenarios and then use Regular Expressions to cover them. Can you post some examples?

Comment: There might be a way to redirect a whole folder...

Comment: An aside; with that many errors, [this question might be useful to you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941433/redirect-404-to-similar-urls)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help guys. I've carried out the suggested course of action from freedev but have created a separate config file within Apache.

Within the httpd.conf file I have added:

```
# Map settings
Include "conf/extra/map.conf"
```

The map.conf file:

```
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteMap url_rewrite_map txt:conf/map.map
    RewriteCond ${url_rewrite_map:$1|NOT_FOUND} !NOT_FOUND
    RewriteRule ^(.*) http://website.com/${url_rewrite_map:$1} [R=301]
```

The map.map file is formatted as:

```
/oldname/   /newname
```

I've added quite a few of the urls for the redirection and so far so good, it isn't having a massive impact on the server like it did when added to .htaccess

Answer (score 3):

Here as you can do with apache httpd

```
RewriteMap escape int:escape
RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower
RewriteMap my_redir_map txt:map_rewrite.txt
RewriteCond  ${my_redir_map:${lowercase:${escape:%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}}}}  ^(.+)$
RewriteRule .*  http://%1 [R=301,L]
```

I use this rewrite rules usually directly inside apache httpd configuration.
Inside the map_rewrite.txt file you have a tab delimited file with the list of redirect in the following format:

```
www.example.it/tag/nozze                www.example.it/categoria/matrimonio
www.example.it/tag/pippo                www.example.it/pluto
www.example.it/tag/ancora               www.google.com
```

Would be much easier if you can generalize the approach because the redirect have a common pattern. But if not, in this case you only need to add the redirected url into the list.
Take care to study the RewriteMap configuration, because you can also write the list into a different format, for example like a database table.

Please pay attention to this: I have added `escape` and `lowercase` only because there are accents into the urls I need to write. If your urls doesn't have accents, you can remove both.

If you want implement these redirects in php, here the code you need:

```
 <?php
 $dest_url = "http://example.com/path...";
 header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
 header("Location: ".$dest_url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a PHP page to operate as a 404 handler. It should inspect the incoming URL, check if it should map from an old page to a new page, then issue a 301. If there is no mapping then present a 404.

Simply set this page as the 404 handler in your .htaccess and there you go. IIRC this is how Wordpress used to handle 'clean' URLs on IIS before IIS7 brought in URL rewriting without needing a 3rd-party dll.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a redirect class that is on the 404 page that will check the database if there is a valid page to 301 redirect to and redirect it instead of giving the 404 page. If it can't figure that out, it marks it in the database as a 404 page, so it can be fixed later.